# oracle to_date with format doesn't show time

Tags: oracle, format, intervals, to-date

I have simple calculation, I subtract interval from date with time:

```
 select TO_DATE('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  - to_dsinterval('00 0:05:00') from dual;
```

It works fine, the result: **2016-12-05 22:59:59**

but it doesn't work correctly with timezones, so the next approach solves the problem with timezone. I just wrap expression with to_date() one more time

```
select TO_DATE(
TO_DATE('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_dsinterval('00 0:05:00')) from dual;
```

but now it turns time to zeros. Result should be: **2016-12-05 22:59:59** but actual: **2016-12-05 00:00:00**

If I add format to the outer **to_date** as this:

```
select to_date( TO_DATE('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_dsinterval('00 0:05:00'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

The result become very strange: **0005-12-16 00:00:00**
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Result of subtraction is already date. You don't need another `to_date()` and this not solves problem with time zones. If you want some operation on timezones please use `timestamp at time zone`

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` data type does not support any time zone functions, you must use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` for that.

Your query

```
SELECT TO_DATE( TO_DATE('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DSINTERVAL('00 0:05:00'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM dual;
```

does following:

1. Create a `DATE` '2016-12-05 23:04:59'
2. Subtract interval '00 0:05:00'
3. Cast to a `VARCHAR2` (using `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` format)
4. Cast to a `DATE` using `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format

In case your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` would be equal to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` this query returns correct output.

Use this one:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DSINTERVAL('00 0:05:00')
FROM dual;
```

`TO_DATE(...` works as well. If you need time zone support you must do:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2016-12-05 23:04:59 Europe/Berlin', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') - TO_DSINTERVAL('00 0:05:00')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: `DATE` dataypes can have `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` arithmetic performed on them. If you do `SELECT DUMP( TO_DATE('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DSINTERVAL('00 0:05:00') ) FROM DUAL` returns `Typ=13` which is a `DATE` datatype so there is no implicit cast to a `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

[`TO_DATE( char, fmt, nls )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) takes `VARCHAR2` arguments.

Performing `TO_DATE('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_dsinterval('00 0:05:00')` returns a `DATE` datatype which when you pass it to `TO_DATE()` oracle will cast it to a `VARCHAR2` datatype so it matches the expected datatype of the argument (implicitly calling `TO_CHAR( value, NLS_DATE_FORMAT )` to perform this cast) and then convert this back to a `DATE` datatype.

You just need to do:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2016-12-05 23:04:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
         - to_dsinterval('00 0:05:00')
FROM   DUAL;
```

If you want to handle time zones then use a `TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE` and just convert it to whatever timezone you want to store the date at:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-12-05 23:04:59 Europe/Paris' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM   DUAL;
```

(Will create your timestamp in Paris' time zone and convert it to the correct time in the UTC time zone).